# Partitioning and installing Voyage Linux

Tags: debian, partition, system-installation

I am trying to install [Voyage Linux](http://linux.voyage.hk) 0.8.0 (a distribution based off Debian) on a [Soekris Net4801](http://soekris.com/products/net4801.html). I would like to have two partitions, one for the operating system and another one for data.

I have been following the instructions on the Voyage website for [installing Voyage with PXE boot](http://linux.voyage.hk/content/getting-started-pxe-boot-v08x) but instead of running `/usr/local/sbin/format-cf.sh /dev/hda` because that only makes 1 partition, I have manually done the following things before running `voyage.update`.

**1.** Used `fdisk` to partition the disk as so:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         199     1598436   83  Linux
/dev/sda2             200         242      345397+  83  Linux
```

**2.** Created ext2 filesystems on both partitions:

```
mkfs.ext2 /dev/sda1
mkfs.ext2 /dev/sda2
```

**3.** Run `tune2fs` on each filesystem as is done in `format-cf.sh`:

```
tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/sda1 ROOT_FS
tune2fs -i 0 -c 0 /dev/sda2 DATA_FS
```

I then ran `voyage.update` and installed Voyage to `/dev/sda1` yet when I rebooted, just after starting SSHd, the whole thing rebooted and seems to be stuck in an endless loop.

How do I fix this? Did I do something wrong installing Voyage like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer, but I managed to solve the problem by downgrading from Voyage 0.8.0 to Voyage 0.7.5 which installed fine after following the above steps.

Comment: As this corresponds to Debian Squeeze 6.0.2 with Linux Kernel 2.6.38, it would be fine for me. At least this is a workaround as long as you can't figure out more details to work towards the root cause of your initial problem.